Looking for a font / typeface that looks almost like roman characters, but isn't
I'm looking for a font that falls into a sort of "uncanny valley" territory where the text characters look frustratingly almost like English, but, upon closer inspection, are definitely not English. My main inspirations for what I'm looking for is those weird, uncanny texts in AI-generated images, and also this Splatoon font:

Thank you!
